# movsb asm not working as expected

Tags: linux, assembly, x86, nasm

From a tutorial I got that movsb will copy data from `ds:si` to `es:di`. But in my case it's not working.

1. While try to debugging with gdb i cannot able to print values in s1 and s2 which decleared in .data section and .bss section respectively.
2. Any one please help how we can see value of s2 ,while printing $p2 i got void in debugging?
3. Why the value of s2 don't change with that of s1 here ?
   code is given below

```asm
section  .text
global _start
_start:
mov esi,s1
mov edi,s2
cld
rep movsb
mov edx,20
mov ecx,s2
mov ebx,1
mov eax,4
int 80h 
mov eax,1
int 80h
section .data
s1 db  'qwerty',0
section .bss
s2  resb 20
```

Comment: when using "rep movsb", you should set CX to the amount of bytes you want to move

Comment: `ecx` in 32 bit mode, like you seem to be (in 64b mode you should avoid `int 80h`). I.e. add `mov ecx, 20` ahead of `rep movsb` to transfer 20 bytes.

Comment: tanx all understood

Answer (score 2):

When Linux starts your process, all your registers (including ECX) will be zero, except for ESP.  (The ABI says they can hold garbage, but Linux chooses zero to avoid info leaks.)

Thus [`rep movsb`](http://felixcloutier.com/x86/REP:REPE:REPZ:REPNE:REPNZ.html) will copy zero bytes.  It's memcpy, not strcpy, it doesn't look at the data.

This is why your program doesn't just crash, like you'd expect from using `rep movsb` without setting ECX first.